# Setup a ssh local port forwarding with Python's sshtunnel

Tags: python, networking, ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I've got the following open ssh client command to setup a local port forwarding:

```
ssh -i <keyfile> -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -L <localPort>:<remoteHost>:<remotePort> <user>@<remoteServerIP> -fN
```

How can I do exactly the same in Python with the sshtunnel library?
https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The sshtunnel's documentation has no example for using key files, in this case the key file contains a RSA PRIVATE KEY.

Comment: There is an example how to use keys: https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-2

Comment: @Maurice Meyer - The example assumes a password protected pkey authentication, but I have a private key file. I guess I have to call the API method read_private_key_file() somehow.